# How do I reference model attributes in module instance methods in RoR 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to move my downcase_email method out of my User class since I've got multiple Classes which will need to have their emails downcased. I'm not sure if this is the right approach, but I created a module and moved the method into it.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include ModelUtilities

  before_save   :downcase_email

  # downcase_email was previously here
  #
  # def downcase_email
  #   self.email = email.downcase
  # end 
end
```

file in lib/model_utilities.rb

```
module ModelUtilities

  def downcase_email
    self.email = email.downcase
  end

end
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass):

lib/model_utilities.rb:6:in `downcase_email'
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `self.email = email.downcase if email.present?`.
Also, you better use `before_validation` callback, not `before_save`. And do downcasing only if email chaged, not all the time. `before_validation   :downcase_email, if: :email_changed?`

Comment: @xlembouras It is. The error would be on "include" if that was the problem :)

Comment: check what coming in self and use self.email.downcase instead of email.downcase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You are doing everything correct. But what about scenario when email itself is empty/nil? Then you will get 'undefined method downcase for nil class'*

***So just edit your code like this***

> nil.try(:something) wont throw error - its like mini exception handler

```
 def downcase_email
    self.email = email.try(:downcase)
 end
```

Comment: Accepting this since it was exactly what the problem was... I went down a rabbit hole!

Answer (score 4):

It's a good common approach, but Rails is proposing concerns for this case.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

In your case, the code will be:

```
# file in models/concerns/model_utilities.rb

module ModelUtilities
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_validation :downcase_email
  end

  def downcase_email
    email.downcase!
  end

end


# include your concern
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include ModelUtilities
end
```

Look `before_validation` can be moved to concern.